# Using AJAX code inside a Joomla article

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

How to add AJAX code inside a Joomla article by using a third party module like Flexi Custom Code?
I have a form inside my article and want to make a submit for this form without refreshing the page.

I read some pages talking about this, but I did not understand how to.

Answer (score 0):

We have written an exhaustive and easy to use guide on how to use Ajax in Joomla. You can find it [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-use-joomlas-ajax-interface-component-com_ajax).

In short, you will need to create a function ending by "Ajax" in the module in question that will check for the submitted information and that will return an output according to the submitted information. A valid function name can be funcAjax. Just make sure you pass "func" as the "method" in the ajax URL call.

Comment: I'm using custom codes inside article not k2 module

Comment: Which file should the Ajax request call? Is the file within Joomla?

Comment: Yes I added codes within same page of form inside module (Flexi Custom Code) and loaded module inside article, but the problem here is calling url from Ajax I'm using    <?php echo JPATH_BASE . '/tools/****.php'; ?> but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use free extension like [sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer) Using this plugin, you can very easily insert html and javascript codes inside article.

here is a video tutorial on how to use it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiFa1Jq8igQ

Comment: The problem is Ajax doesn't work with these modules, how to use ajax url with joomla?

Comment: Hi, Why ajax will not work within these extension. You need to upload a php file to your webserver which will process your form. Then add the forms html and javascript inside the joomla article using Sourcerer plugin. It must work. 
Do you have the code's ready for the ajax form ? 

Here is an example of simple ajax forms.  https://gist.github.com/ajtroxell/6731408

When you will use jQuery in Joomla, Make sure you convert all `$` to `jQuery` in scripts

Comment: How to call php url for joomla in ajax? Im using     <?php echo JPATH_BASE . '/tools/****.php'; ?>